# Calculating Cos inverse to find angle degree

Tags: java, angle, trigonometry

So, right now I am trying to calculate the angles of a right triangle using the inverse of Cosine. However, I don't really know how to do it. I know the equation, just not how to convert into code. The equation would be:: Cos-1(A/C); However, that does not seem to work in Java. I also tried

```
angleX = (int) Math.acos(sideC / sideA);
```

Comment: what is the data types of sideC  and sideA?

Comment: Doesn't work?  Of course it does.  You realize that every language uses radians instead of degrees for angles, right?  Shouldn't angles be doubles and not ints?  Java is fine; it's your understanding that is lacking.

Comment: can you post the compete code and expected result

Comment: main problem is you cast it to int .so if it is 0.x then you get 0 .do you want the degrees instead of radians?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sideC and sideA were integers, one would have integer division (2 / 3 == 0).
If you do not expect a result in radians, but degrees, a conversion is needed.
As double is an approximation, use round too.

```
if (sideA == 0) { ... }
angleX = (int) Math.round(
        Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(((double)sideC) / sideA)));
```